# Help me identify this Mini Bonsai

Tags: identification, trees, bonsai

I bought this mini bonsai from home depot, but it didn't have a specific bonsai name, so I'm trying to guess what is this kind of bonsai?
[image: the mini bonsai]

[image: the mini bonsai]

Answer (score 9):

It looks like Ficus benjamina, though its hard to be sure of scale in terms of size of the leaves from the photo - image and info here https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ficus_benjamina. Your plant doesn't look like a bonsai, it just looks like a Ficus benjamina that's lost some of its leaves, but instructions as to how to make a bonsai from this plant can be found here http://guide.makebonsai.com/bonsai_species_guide_training.asp?SpeciesID=5018

There is another, much smaller leaved version of this plant which is very similar, and would likely be more suitable for bonsai, and that is Ficus benjamina 'Too Little', image here so you can compare leaf size https://www.rareflora.com/ficusben2lil.htm

Comment: Nope, I think you are right the regular Ficus benjamina and this is no Bonsai unless it was transplanted into this black, nursery pot, WEIRD.  Anyone that wants to grow Bonsai needs a 'hands on class' with a bonsai expert.  Good luck trying to grow a Bonsai by book.  Being able to keep a bonsai alive is the sign somebody knows plants.  Even us oh so educated and experienced plant people have a TOUGH time with growing Bonsai.  Other wise you'll have a sweet Ficus, but get that saucer emptied everytime you water.  Don't overdo or underdo the watering.  If you purchased this as a bonsai....

Comment: The roots will not do well with this much soil.  Too few roots for this size plant.  I'd repot it in a pot half this size.  Find a well lit spot, use distilled or bottled water, no drafts (unusual sporadic puffs of air of a different temperature).  Keep it in that spot.  This pot will be fine when it grows decent roots and doubles its canopy.  Very very careful with fertilizer.  Right now I am not seeing deficiencies.  I also see new growth.  Perhaps leaving it in this pot is fine but do not overwater!!  If it continues to fail, then I would repot in a smaller pot with potting soil.

Answer (score 2):

This is a Ficus, A Benjamima I think. This is suitable for inside as it is semi tropical. You must repot this tree, buy a packet of Bonsai soil mix and add some gravel , gravel is essential to let the soil drain , a little bark chips would help. Get a pot which you fill to just below the rim , otherwise excess water will lie in the pot and start to rot the roots.
Luckily this species does not mild getting dry from time to time. But it must have lots of light , a light bulb is not enough. Put it by a bright window. The bathroom is ideal as this plant likes moist air.
Outside Bonsais are easier as they get Moisture, strong light , and fresh air , and rain for free. Never let your Bonsai dry out . Good luck.